# testing a huge decomposed method and its inner helper methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I've been writing a lot of unit tests recently. There's a scenario to which I cannot find a clean solution...

Let's say you have a beast of a method:

```
public void bigMethod() {
    // a lot of code goes in here
}
```

To make your life easier and your code cleaner you'd usually decompose such a beast into smaller inner methods:

```
public void bigMethod() {
    a();
    b();
    c();
    // etc.
}
```

You can test all of the inner methods (a(), b(), c() etc.) independently. The problem is the bigMethod() which should also be tested but the only thing it's doing is chaining calls of some other methods and those have been thoroughly tested already!

How do you approach such a scenario? You cannot just leave bigMethod() untested because you need to be sure that a(), b() and c() are called in there IN PROPER ORDER. But writing a test for bigMethod() will lead to a lot of DUPLICATION IN TESTS. And reducing this duplication there every time is a lot of hassle since you'll be doing that OFTEN.

One idea that comes to my mind is:

```
public void bigMethod() {
    helperA.a();
    helperB.b();
    helperC.c();
    // etc.
}
```

In this scenario you test every helper class and then make sure bigMethod() calls them inOrder. Nice and clean but introduces a lot of very small classes into the project.

Help test ninjas!

Comment: `Nice and clean but introduces a lot of very small classes into the project.` Small, clean, simple, easily testable, mockable, reusable, and with one responsibility.  Doesn't sound so bad to me...

Answer (score 2):

Typically the best practice is to have your unit tests test the `bigMethod()`, as it's the publicly exposed method, and for the tests to be ignorant of the inner, private helper methods.

Tests that know too much about the inner workings of a class tend to be brittle and have to be heavily modified if you refactor the internal implementation of `bigMethod()`, as you've pointed out.

So my advice would be to rewrite your tests to focus on `bigMethod()` and then not have to worry about code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't find a good solution is that splitting up the method into sequential pieces didn't really improve things.  In fact, it may have made debugging harder since you had to share state across method boundaries, probably using instance variables.

I know this isn't the answer you wanted to hear, but if you really want to improve the code, you'll step back and re-analyze what `bigMethod` does and rewrite it, separating its various functions into classes with appropriate interfaces.  Ideally you'd also refactor the places where `bigMethod` is called, but I realize that may be out of scope for the task you've been assigned.

Comment: I disagree. Splitting up the method into sequential pieces really improves readability. It's called the "extract till' you drop" :)   http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.objectmentor.com%2Farticles%2F2009%2F09%2F11%2Fone-thing-extract-till-you-drop&ei=N0h8UPf6B6fA0QXRlYGgAg&usg=AFQjCNG2db-4FvjCtyT70J5HIBu0XKi1qQ

Comment: That all depends on the original code and how it is broken up.  Splitting just for the sake of splitting can be good or bad, and in my experience (from reading thousands of lines of legacy code) is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @Mik378: Bob Martin is a master at writing up bad advice in a way that makes it look like great advice. The code he used was suited to being broken into very small parts; a lot of code is like that, but some code isn't. I had a colleague once who used to mindlessly pound the 'extract method' refactoring in Eclipse until our code was an incomprehensible, unmaintainable, mess of one-liners. He probably read a lot of Bob Martin.

Comment: @Tom Anderson I think it's really a matter of taste. As far as I'm concerned, less algorithms and less comments there are, better I am :) => splitting promotes that. And quality of splitting is also very déterminant. Of course, one developer could quickly make things horribly...

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly, all the below text makes sense if `a()`, `b()` and `c()` are public methods.**

`bigMethod()` test focus on the consequences of the internal calls, meaning calls of `a()` followed by `b()` and followed by `c()`.

**It's totally another scenario than testing each of these methods independently.**

So according to me, adding a specific test for `bigMethod()` does not reveal some duplication but instead a new interesting case to check: **the collaboration of the internal calls**.

I would keep your first version of code and test it :)

Actually, this seems to be the similar common issue with project delivery:

Assume three projects developed separately and finally gathering them.

Three possibilities of doing:

- Test only the three projects independently
- Wait for testing solely the mixed of the three projects
- Test these both ways !

Logically, the third possibility is wished; the same for unit testing.

`a()` or `b()` or `c()` could have an unexpected behaviour that does not prevent `bigMethod()` to have an expected result and inversely, `bigMethod()` could have an unexpected result despite of the successful tests of the independent methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the solution doesn't appear clearly to you is because you haven't really thought out and defined the nature of `a()`, `b()` and `c()`. You definitely need to figure out which of the following `a()`, `b()` and `c()` are :

1. Internal, inseparable subparts of `bigMethod()` that make no sense outside of it.
2. Methods that are part of the class's public contract, contribute to its cohesion and can be called independently from the outside.
3. Methods that after all don't really belong in the class. Taking them out would benefit to the class's cohesion and make them more easily reusable.

Once you've figured that out, the answer to how to test them is easy.

1. Just test `bigMethod()` as the atomic block it is, don't try to fiddle with the visibility scope of its internal subparts to make them testable.
2. Test `a()`, `b()` and `c()` independently. Then to test `bigMethod()`, use a partial mock and just verify that the submethods are called in the right order. You could also test `bigMethod()`'s result, making it kind of an integration test more than a unit test, with the duplication problems you mentioned.
3. Test `a()`, `b()` and `c()` independently. Then to test `bigMethod()`, use mocks for their objects and verify that `bigMethod()` talks to these objects correctly.